# Renaming request: [googlecontactsapi] to [google-contacts-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

All of the [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) tags use a - between the words this makes things easier to read.

I just ran across [googlecontactsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlecontactsapi) which does not follow this convention.

I would like to suggest that it be renamed.

Comment: There is another [tag:google-contacts], which seems to be similar to this tag.

Comment: [Google-Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) is the web application [google-contacts-api](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/) is the developer api for accessing the data in Google Contacts.   I think you did a merge of the google-drive and the Google-calendar web app related tags into the main one as well.   Up to you if you want to do that again.

Comment: The tag wiki tells a different tale... I'm assuming that the wiki needs to be updated?

Comment: When do the wikis not need to be updated.   Give me a minute i will go clean them up

Comment: Yep, I don't see much of a reason to keep multiple tags. I'll post an answer and let the community to decide. And thanks so much for cleaning up the wikis.

Comment: Done hows that :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort in cleaning it up, but we had a large discussion a few years back about not using Wikipedia definition in the excerpt. (See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000)). The decision was to summarize the definition in our own words, and talk about how we can use the tag on Stack Overflow. (I get it that tag excerpts are a bit hard, sorry for that)

Comment: I wanted to write you should not use google-contacts-api its old crap and should just die you should use people-api its the new api but i tried to keep it neutral.   I will go give it another attempt.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I agree with the main idea here that all the Google API tags are hyphenated, and for consistency, the [googlecontactsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlecontactsapi) tag needs to be renamed to [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api). There are two other reasons for renaming the tag,

1. The official name is ["Google Contacts API"](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/), and not "GoogleContactsAPI".
2. It was decided long back that using hyphens makes the tag name clear [Should tags take the form foobar or foo-bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/should-tags-take-the-form-foobar-or-foo-bar).

So I support the renaming of the tag.

That said, there is another [google-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts), whose tag excerpt reads:

> Google Contacts API allows client applications to view and update a user's contacts.

The questions in the tag are primarily related to the Google Contacts API. The few questions that are about the Google Contacts web application are not on-topic here as such, and probably are on-topic on either Web Applications Stack Exchange or Super User. So, my suggestion here is to:

1. Rename [google-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts) as [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api).
2. Merge [googlecontactsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlecontactsapi) to the renamed tag [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api).
3. (Optional) Add the original [google-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts) as a synonym for [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api), to redirect users of the old tag to the new one.

Comment: I support all of the above.